# What's the magic of randomization?

Tags: stratification, random-allocation

I've read that one can perform A/B tests & effect size inference given that a population was randomly sampled and allocated to A & B groups. You simply give the treatment to group B and the lift is B in attributable to the treatment exposure.

Sound too good to be true? I think it is.

Suppose you have some population w/ 100 randomization units. You randomly select 50 for the treatment group. "100 choose 50" is 10^29 possible A/B splits; regardless of which set you get, the split is "randomized" and appropriate for inference (what I find highly suspect.)

Some variables are continuous and others are categorical. For categorical variables, one could stratify; ex, divide the population of 100 randomization units into homogenous subpopulations of all-male and all-female, randomly assign to A or B then aggregate. (`A-male & A-female -> A`.)

Assuming that there are an even number of males (or females) in the total population, it can be ensured that each sex is equally represented in both groups, A & B. This ensures that sex is orthogonal to treatment exposure, not confounding it. If the number of males is odd, you'll get close to orthogonal (close enough? I'm not sure.) In fact, in a post-experiment regression model, one could condition on sex and its interaction with treatment exposure to learn even more - hurray!

This process could be repeatedly recursively for all categorical variables. But what's not obvious is stratification on continuous variables. I've seen such variables broken into quantiles (ex: 0-10th percentile, ..., 90-100th percentile) then treat these quantile-based subpopulations then perform the same process as detailed for categorical variables.

At any rate, randomization to me, doesn't seem to be a reliable mechanism for "these populations are as similar as possible" because that would be an optimization problem, not a shuffling problem.

If there's any imbalance in whatever metric we're studying, then a vanilla T-test isn't appropriate. There are methods such as difference in differences (DiD) that accommodate pre-experiment differences in means. But this method assumes a parallel trends assumption, which again is not something guaranteed by shuffling.

Philosophically, I think randomization is over-hyped because the alternative optimization problem is simply too computationally intensive.

If someone could offer a proper defense of why randomization where an imbalance of means across A/B is acceptable, I'm very interested in learning more.

Edit: wow the number of upvotes and downvotes this post received! And even close requests… I did not foresee how polarizing/political this question would be for certain academic communities.

Comment: To be clear, is your primary argument _against randomization_ rooted in the fact that I could, in principle, receive an unlucky shuffle in which one of the two groups has a higher proportion of a moderator?  And that since I can not guard against this, then randomization is...what exactly?

Comment: You could try a simulation to convince yourself that it works.

Comment: @demetriPananos for both the variable of interest and every covariate, you will have some degree of imbalance. This imbalance could be minimized but not by luck alone. And whether that imbalance is large enough to confound inference is the question of interest.

Comment: @Adrian - simulations as in A/A tests? Aka randomly shuffle n times and each time see if the delta between groups (no treatment exposure) has a p-value less than alpha.

Comment: If you know which covariates are important and can stratify/block on them, that's great. But in most real-world problems, there are a zillion covariates that could make *some* difference. We usually don't know them all and can't measure them all, even if we had no trouble with the computational optimization. Randomization helps (not perfectly, but substantially!) to guard us against pre-existing between-group differences on variables that we haven't even measured yet.

Comment: I don't think this is "political."  I downvoted it because IMHO it is framed in a provocative way that merely reflects a lack of research.  That kind of question is never on topic here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> for both the variable of interest and every covariate, you will have some degree of imbalance.

Yes, this is true.  That is just part of life.  Even if we could record every variable we think effects the outcome, there is always the possibility we have failed to recored *some* variable and our split has favoured one group with that variable.

You could, in principle, compute the probability of this happening.  I would imagine that while you could not rule this out as a possibility, you may find the probability so low as to be negligible.

> This imbalance could be minimized but not by luck alone. And whether that imbalance is large enough to confound inference is the question of interest.

It is definitively not confounding, which is a correlation between exposure and outcome due to some third variable.  Any single sample is not confounded because of an imbalance.  Detecting a difference where one may not exist is baked into our test statistic anyway, and so I'm not really seeing the problem you're raising.

Comment: So suppose that you wanted to see if Gatorade had a significant effect on speed for runners. Unbeknownst to you, females skip breakfast more often than males and suppose runs are measured exclusively in mornings. If there was a higher prevalence of women in the treatment group, we might  overestimate the effect of Gatorade on run time simply because the caloric increase was larger for women than men and the sexes were not evenly allocated. At some point this becomes a problem. But at what point?

Comment: @jbuddy_13 Ok, this may be the case for a single experiment.  How likely is it to be replicated in future experiments?  Is it important that we replicate?  Even in cases where things are _perfect_, we still run a risk of making a false positive due to chance.

Are you at all concerned with these cases?  Why or why not?

Comment: There is inherent risk when doing inference.  That's just how science operates.  The  protection against these chance outcomes is replication -- reliably showing the result across time and location.  Surely, the chance such a split would occur for each replication is nigh 0.  Is that not sufficient?

Comment: Makes sense in lens of replication, thanks!

Comment: Not just for replication. This is literally what statistical tests are for. If your sample is small than the treatment and control groups might not be unbalanced even if you randomized them. But the probability of that goes down as the sample size goes up. And contrary to the answer, we DO calculate the probability of this happening: that is what a p value tells us. A p value of .05 means that there is a less than 5% chance that the difference we estimated between the two groups is just due to sampling error.

Answer (score 0):

First, you are conflating two different claims. The first is a claim about why random *samples* are important for *generalization*. If you are trying to generalize estimates (causal or otherwise) from a sample to a population, it really helps if the sample is randomly drawn from the population, because a result called the central limit theorem tells us that no only are estimates from random samples unbiased, but it tells us how likely an estimate from a random sample is to be wrong due to dumb luck. This is the basis of "significance tests" and "confidence intervals."

The second claim is that randomly *assigning* a treatment variable allows us to generate unbiased estimates of the *causal effect* of that variable *within the sample*.

Here is an intuitive explanation for why that is the case.

Let's say you are interested in measuring the causal effect of A on B. Absent random assignment you can't just look at the association between A and B, because that association might be due to a confounding variable C.

But let's think about what is required for a variable to be a confounder. C can only confound our estimate of the relationship between A and B if it is correlated with *both* A and B. Only if this is true does C offer a "back door path" between A and B that doesn't involve A causing C. If C is only correlated with B but not correlated with A, then it can't confound our estimate of the causal effect of A on B, because there is no way that C could cause us to *think* A and B are related.

This means that, if we had a way to ensure that *no* other variable is correlated with A (except for things that A *causes* to happen) then we don't have to worry about *any* confounding variables. This is what random assignment does. If your value of A is determined only by a truly random process, then we can be confident that it is not determined by anything else, because a truly random process is by definition not correlated with anything else. This means that if we see that a randomly assigned variable A is correlated with B, we know that this can only be because A *caused* B.

(this same logic allows us to be sure that the relationship isn't due to B causing A, because if A was randomly assigned, it can't be caused by anything other than the random assignment itself)

Note that none of this depends on whether A, B, or C are categorical or continuous, or on how they are distributed in the population. Randomization controls for all possible confounders, no matter what they are or how they are measured.

This doesn't mean that random assignment is magical. Perfect randomization can be hard to achieve in some case. And if the sample as a whole was not randomly drawn, then the results may not be generalizable to the larger population. Randomization also doesn't tell you *how* A caused B. And in lots of cases it just isn't possible. But it really does work.

Comment: Thanks for investing time and energy into this answer! Some follow ups: what amount correlation can we say is “uncorrelated”, ex +/- 15%, 5%, etc? Because 0.0% with no rounding is presumably unattainable in most cases.

Comment: I was defining A as the control group and B as the treatment group. Is it safe to assume that you have same definitions of A & B (where C is the treatment exposure)?

Comment: And with a vanilla T-test in this context when pre-experiment means are imbalanced, I believe the assumption is “true, these means are different but they’re sampled IID from the same distribution and some amount of variation is inherent” - true?

Comment: To your first point about sampling n units from a global population then dividing this sample into 2 groups, A & B… I would argue that there is no guarantee that the “global population” is in fact, one cohesive whole. For example, on a social media platform, there could be influencers, power users and casual users. But one might naively that they compose one population of users. I would argue that by randomly sampling n users, you have no guarantee that these clusters are equally represented before ever splitting into A/B groups. One might not even know that these user clusters exist!

Comment: I was defining A, B and C as VARIABLES. A is the variable that stores whether you got the treatment or not. B is the variable storing your score on whatever outcome metric you care about. C is literally any other phenomenon in the world (age, gender). As for your other questions, there are too many issues to resolve in the comment section of a website.  It seems to me that you haven't had a strong exposure to many of the most foundational ideas in statistics. Which is fine, but if you take a class or get more familiar  with these topics I think your questions will dissolve.